# My desktop icons have gone out of view

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, icons, desktop-environments

I have just two icons on my desktop The Home folder and my Kindle.

Until recently they worked well, However,today, when I turned on my computer, they had vanished. I checked the settings and it said that they were displayed, and when I activated the Trash icon, it appears as it should.

My assumption is that the two icons have wandered off the top of the screen, for reasons best known to themselves. When I click the desktop and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all icons the hit <kbd>Return</kbd> both the Home Folder and My Kindle fire up.

I would appreciate it someone could tell me what commands I should give to get them back on to the screen, *No witty comments like Here boy!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about right-clicking anywhere in the blank area of the Desktop and selecting Organize Desktop by Name?

I'm assuming you don't have multiple monitor configurations, or anything like workspace-specific layouts that isolate icons to specific workspaces.

Comment: That did it thank you. I could only see the very bottom of Kindle, but with Ctrl+A I dragged them back into view. You saved me hours of irritation +

Comment: Just realised what I had done. As you asked, Yes I have two monitors and yes I changed the position of the laptop/smaller screen. I learn something new every  day. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help, and glad to know one of my assumptions was actually spot-on.  ;)